# Find limiting distribution

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

The question is like this:

$X_i$ are i.i.d with $P(X_i\leq x)=1-e^{-x}$. $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Find the limiting distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^nI(X_iS_n>1)$.

It seems that the problem is related to Poisson process.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not meant to read $P(X_i \leq x) = 1 - e^{-x}$?

Comment: @SimonRigby  Sorry, it is a typo.